# How can I download and save all the images shown in a web page?

Tags: images, download, batch-jobs

I want to download the images shown in a web page, for example *https://www.wikiart.org/en/paintings-by-style/art-nouveau-modern*, (the ones under the *All Artworks* tab), and store them in a folder (e.g. */home/boomer/GH/A_nou/*).

How can I achieve this?

I can use `wget` or `curl` for that, but sadly I have no idea of what to do with them.

Also I don't want the intermediate images, (banners, logos, *etc.*), only full size images for everything under the artwork section.

Comment: unfortunately, `wget` return only one image from the needed list of images, this one `<img alt="Artworks by style: Art Nouveau (Modern)" itemprop="image" src="https://uploads5.wikiart.org/images/gustav-klimt/hygeia-detail-of-medicine-1907.jpg!PinterestLarge.jpg" title="Artworks by style: Art Nouveau (Modern)"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Look in the source, search for `.jpg"` and you will see all the images there, notice they are surrounded by double quotes. So save the HTML source to your computer, I chose `/tmp/test_art.html` and I search for `"`, replace with newline, then grep all lines ending with `jpg`, then pass all those lines to wget:

```
wget $(sed 's/"/\n/g;' /tmp/test_art.html| grep 'jpg$')
```

This is really trivial, of course, some sed guru will come along shortly and come up with a one liner, saving the grep ... I think it is too much work for ad hoc stuff like this ... quick and dirty.

You open a terminal and change directory to the directory where you want to store the files:

```
cd /home/boomer/GH/A_nou/
```

Then you run the above command.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/0jarFnhB

I got this done, but only 60 of the images are there, why is this so?

Comment: I guess this comes from the first entry, which contains a !, evil, that!

Before saving the file, you must click "Load More" ... you really want to download 6000 images ? If you want the program to do this, you must use something that can handle JavaScript, such as node.js ... that is not trivial ...